# r.statistics throws invalid reclass rule error despite assigning null to unique value

Tags: raster, grass-gis, nodata

Trying to run `r.statistics` on two raster layers, one a layer of distinct zones produced via `r.clump` (stands) and one a layer of all ones (ones). The areas outside of the immediate region of interest are `NULL` values in the original data.

Below are the lines of code:

```
r.in.gdal input=ones.tif output=ones -o
r.in.gdal input=stands.tif output=stands -o

r.null map=ones null=999999999
r.null map=stands null=999999999

r.statistics base=stands cover=ones method=sum output=forest
```

However, `r.statistics` keeps producing this error:

```
WARNING: Can't have null on the left-hand side of the rule
ERROR: 140725237898080 = 140725237898080 0 - invalid reclass rule
```

How do I set the nulls such that I can run r.statistics on the two layers?

Comment: Have you set the current region to the input rasters?

Comment: Micha, perhaps repeat your comment as full answer along with the link to https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error above is due to calculations being attempted in a computational region that extends outside of the input rasters. So before doing the r.statistics:

```
g.region -p rast=stands
```

FAQ #0 in almost all GRASS raster processes: Pay attention to region settings. GRASS and computational region need to go together like peanut butter and jelly :-)

Here are the details: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region